# How to get for every ID the row with max(TIMESTAMP)?

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following simple select statement:

```
SELECT ID, EVENT, TIMESTAMP from table
order by ID, TIMESTAMP;
```

I now want to get for every ID only the entry with the last timestamp, i.e. with the max(TIMESTAMP). How can I get this? Do I have to use a subquery?

Answer (score 2):

One method uses aggregation:

```
select id, max(timestamp) as timestamp,
       max(event) keep (dense_rank first order by timestamp desc) as event
from t
group by id;
```

The `keep` syntax is Oracles (rather verbose) way of implementing a "first" aggregation function.

Comment: "rather verbose" - as opposed to what other way? I believe most other db products don't implement the first/last aggregate (and analytic) functions at all, never mind the syntax.